# How do get my custom Python code into Azure Machine Learning for use a a ZIP resource?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/) for the Azure Machine Learning Python script module describes using a ZIP file containing code as a resource, but I don't see how to create and upload such a ZIP file in the first place.

How do get my custom Python code into Azure Machine Learning for use as a ZIP resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upload it as a dataset. [Reference.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/) (search for it, as it is not on the first page).

[Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-walkthrough-2-upload-data/#upload-the-dataset-to-machine-learning-studio) on how to upload the dataset.

Comment: Ah, so that's my question: How do I "upload as a dataset" — i.e., where should I put it and what processing do I need to do on it? Any old ZIP will do? Is there a specific location it needs to be in? (And again, I assume there's no automatic way to sync, e.g. with 'git'.)

Comment: No for git, old ZIP will do it. I added the reference for the uploading. When you upload, it is just being uploaded, so you do not want to specifywhere - it will be available from the Datasets section on the Workplace

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc explaining this in details - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/#importing-existing-python-script-modules

Comment: Yes, and the question is: how to "upload as a zip"?